# On click, hiding a DIV while updating MySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a DIV and I want to:

1. Hide the div (display:none) when the user clicks it (I have this part solved)
2. Update a MySQL database (this is what my question pertains to)

I found this script on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13801257/2202638) that I have sitting in the head of my document:

```js
<script>
    function myScript(imageID)  { 
      url="updateDatabase.php?imageID=" + imageID;
      objX=new XMLHttpRequest();
      objX.open("GET",url,false);
      objX.send(null);
      response=objX.responseText;
      document.getElementById('image' + imageID).innerHTML=response;
    }
</script>
```

And here is the DIV's code within the page that uses an imageID set elsewhere in the code to determine which image to load and pass to the script:

```js
echo "
<div id=\"image".$imageID."\">
    <img
        src=\"images/".$imageID.".png\" 
        onclick=\"myScript(".$imageID.");
            document.getElementById('image".$imageID."').style.display = 'none'
    \">
</div>";
```

And here is the updateDatabase.php page that the script refers to. It is one line of PHP that refers to a function defined elsewhere in my code that is used successfully elsewhere in the same site. It runs a series of MySQL queries/inserts/updates.

```js
updateImage($_GET['imageID']);
```

I have successfully made the DIV hide upon being clicked, but I cannot seem to get it to update the database in the same step - that's the missing piece here from me.

I know for a fact that I am successfully passing the desired imageID, because I can correctly output it on this updateDatabase.php page if I so choose. However, I can't get any database activity to occur with it.

From what I gather, this requires a mix of JQuery and/or AJAX. While I have rudimentary knowledge of PHP/MySQL, this is brand new territory for me so any clarification would be very appreciated. I am also new to SO and apologize in advance if I have left out crucial information or ignored a post convention - please let me know if this is the case.

Comment: Well you are saying that DB not updated and you not included the DB query part in question. It is required to understand problem. What the updateImage function did ?

Comment: Kuldeep, thank you for your follow-up question. For the sake of simple testing, I have made the database update a simple query for an image of that ID, and made the updateDatabase.php page attempt to output the imageID out of that query. I can get it to output the $_GET['imageID'] but not the imageID out of the MySQL query.

Comment: It is tough to say anything without checking your code in updateDatabase.php. There can be any DB errors which can be checkout it through relative library's error functions or may through apache error logs.

Comment: Kuldeep, this is the contents of my updateDatabase.php currently:

`<?
$imageID = $_GET['imageID'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (title) VALUES ('1')");
echo $imageID;
?>`

As you can see, it is very simple. I check in phpMyAdmin to see if the table has been updated in order to verify it is working. However, I can't get it to work with any of the code from the answers at this time. The page also outputs $_GET['imageID'] so I can be sure this is still working.

Comment: Try with mysql_error function after query if some error get through it. Other wise check your DB settings for application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by dissecting the code in [this](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp) tutorial, which demonstrated exactly how to lay out the "moving parts" of this type of operation. Anyone that has a similar question to mine should use this as a reference; it has full bug-free code for every sample page.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.

```
onclick="myScript('.$imageID.')"
```

And the function:

```
function myScript(imageID) {
    $('#image'+imageID).hide();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'updateDatabase.php?imageID='+imageID;
      async: true,
      type: 'get',
      success: function(data) {
           $('#image'+imageID).html(data);
            $('#image'+imageID).show();
      },
      error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {  
           if(jqXHR.status&&jqXHR.status==400){
                alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
           }else{
               alert("Something went wrong");
           }
      }
   });
```

Now, the data.response will depend on the exact nature of your JSON being returned. If it's not JSON but raw HTML, that's not much different.
Look at the docs on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Hello Jono, thank you for your quick response. I have implemented your function as follows:

function myScript(imageID) {
    $('#image'+imageID).hode();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'updateDatabase.php?imageID='+imageID;
      async: true,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
         $('#image'+imageID).html(data.response);
         $('#image'+imageID).show();
      }
   });

I removed a few ' characters that did not seem to be properly placed. However, the MySQL queries are still not running in updateDatabase.php. Can you see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery

```
$.ajax({
 url:"updateDatabase.php?imageID=" + imageID,
 type:"GET",//Default
 success:function(data, status){
   if(status){
     $("#'image"+ imageID).html(data);
     // do as per need
   }else{
    // else part
   }
 },
 error:function(-----){
--------------
 }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Arvind, thank you for your response! Could you elaborate on how I may implement this - I am completely new to JQuery.

Comment: Please note - I tried Jono's Ajax code within his answer and am having some trouble with it as well.

Comment: I think his normal javascript ajax code is fine enough. As his problem relate to server side and he is able to get imageid through $_GET.